# "all they did was (to) leave"

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

I've come across this sentence:

> [...] I've spent my all life making people happy when all they did *was leave*.

Shouldn't it be "To leave" or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an infinitive is preceded by an auxiliary verb and a phrase ending in *do* (such as *What I did was*, *All we do is*, etc.), the *to* is optional.

From *Practical English Usage*, 91.5:

> Expressions like *All I did was*, *What I do is*, etc can be followed by an infinitive without *to*.
>
> *All I did was **(to) give** him a little push.
>
>   What a fire-door does is **(to) delay** the spread of a fire.
>
>   The only thing we can do is **(to) accept**.*

Comment: While you can leave the "to" in, for some reason it sounds off to me (native AmEn). Maybe it's because it's rarely included?